# capture an event inside an iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iframe

I have this screen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ2og.png)

it is accessed through this code snippet of this aspx file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fynOu.png)

and here is the iframe file itself, with some flags:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oJgz.png)

I need to access these flags, and trigger an alert event for every change that is made in these flag boxes, but I can't

I need to access the elements within the iframe, to trigger an alert at each event of checking or unchecking the flags within the iframe...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: DataExtractRelMeta.aspx
<Loader Mode="Frame" Url="/MereoGR.EstatisticasRelatorios/RelMetaF.aspx">
                                            <LoadMask ShowMask="true" Msg="={msgMask}" />